# Error 2147317562 (800288C6) Duplicate ID in inheritance hierarchy

Tags: vb6

When I tried opening VB application (which has .Net usercontrols embedded) I got error saying "error while loading the project" and .Net user controls are not loaded.

Then I tried adding components to the VB application then I got the error: "2147317562 (800288C6) Duplicate ID in inheritance hierarchy".

I searched in net and understood that registry settings for VB are modified to VB5. How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, that something has corrupted your registry.

Try re-installing Visual Basic 6.0 including the latest Service Packs and then re-register all your additional COM components.

Comment: I have done the same thing but still problem persists. Any ideas??